# Pandas groupby apply slow - alternative suggestions?

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby, finance

I have a small toy dataset of 23 hours of irregular time series data (financial tick data) with millisecond granularity, roughly 1M rows. By irregular I mean that the timestamps are not evenly spaced. I also have a column 'mid' with some values too.

I am trying to group by e.g. 2 minute buckets to calculate the absolute difference of 'mid', and then taking the median, in the following manner:

```
df.groupby(["RIC", pd.Grouper(freq='2min')]).mid.apply(
            lambda x: np.abs(x[-1] - x[0]) if len(x) != 0 else 0).median()
```

Note: 'RIC' is just another layer of grouping I am applying before the time bucket grouping.

Basically, I am telling pandas to group by every `[ith minute : ith + 2 minute]` intervals, and in each interval, take the last `(x[-1])` and the first `(x[0])` 'mid' element, and take its absolute difference. I am doing this over a range of 'freqs' as well, e.g. 2min, 4min, ..., up to 30min intervals.

This approach works completely fine, but it is awfully slow because of the usage of pandas' .apply function. I am aware that .apply doesn't take advantage of the built in vectorization of pandas and numpy, as it is computationally no different to a for loop, and am trying to figure out how to achieve the same without having to use apply so I can speed it up by several orders of magnitude.

Does anyone know how to rewrite the above code to ditch .apply? Any tips will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the pandas groupby.apply [webpage](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#:%7E:text=While%20apply%20is%20a%20very%20flexible%20method%2C%20its,to%20use%20them%20before%20reaching%20for%20apply.%20Parameters):

> "While apply is a very flexible method, its downside is that using it
> can be quite a bit slower than using more specific methods like agg or
> transform. Pandas offers a wide range of method that will be much
> faster than using apply for their specific purposes, so try to use
> them before reaching for apply."

Therefore, using `transform` should be a lot faster.

```
grouped = df.groupby(["RIC", pd.Grouper(freq='2min')])
abs(grouped.mid.transform("last") - grouped.mid.transform("first")).median()
```